# How to check which words from a list are contained in a string?

Tags: python, string, parsing, matching, any

I was looking to collect each word from a list that is included in a string in python. I found some solutions but so far i get:

```
data = "Today I gave my dog some carrots to eat in the car"
tweet = data.lower()                             #convert to lower case
split = tweet.split()

matchers = ['dog','car','sushi']
matching = [s for s in split if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
print(matching)
```

The result is

```
['dog', 'carrots', 'car']
```

How do I fix that the result is only dog and car without adding spaces to my matchers?

Also how would I remove any $ signs (as example) from the data string but no other special characters like @?

Comment: Also can anybody explain how the line "matching = [s for s in split if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]" works? What is the meaning of s and xs?

Comment: Do an equality test: `xs == s` instead of `xs in s`?

Comment: _"can anybody explain how the line "matching = ..." works:"_ Look up [list comprehensions](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+list+comprehension)

Comment: _"how would I remove any $ signs:"_ Look up [how to replace characters in a string](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+replace+characters+in+a+string+python)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please restrict yourself to one question per post. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
How do I fix that the result is only dog and car without adding spaces to my matchers?
```

To do this with your current code, replace this line:

```
matching = [s for s in split if any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
```

With this:

```
matching = []
# iterate over all matcher words
for word in matchers:
    if word in split:  # check if word is in the split up words
        matching.append(word)  # add word to list
```

You also mention this:

```
Also how would I remove any $ signs (as example) from the data string but no other special characters like @?
```

To do this, I would create a list that contains characters you want to remove, like so:

```
things_to_remove = ['$', '*', '#']  # this can be anything you want to take out
```

Then, simply strip each character from the tweet string before you split it.

```
for remove_me in things_to_remove:
    tweet = tweet.replace(remove_me, "")
```

So a final code block that demonstrates all of these topics:

```
data = "Today I@@ gave my dog## some carrots to eat in the$ car"
tweet = data.lower()                             #convert to lower case

things_to_remove = ['$', '*', '#']

for remove_me in things_to_remove:
    tweet = tweet.replace(remove_me, "")
print("After removeing characters I don't want:")
print(tweet)

split = tweet.split()

matchers = ['dog','car','sushi']

matching = []
# iterate over all matcher words
for word in matchers:
    if word in split:  # check if word is in the split up words
        matching.append(word)  # add word to list
print(matching)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also the reply from @jarmod was very elegant and worked too. "Do an equality test: xs == s instead of xs in s?"

Comment: shorter `matching = set(matchers) & set(split)`